# Add a modal dialog into Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, modal-dialog

I want to add a Ajax link into my application. When I click on the link it should pop up a modal dialog which contains event's details..
I add this link in my helper class.

```
 link_to(event.name, events_path(@event), :remote => true
```

Then I create js file to insert content into hidden div.

```
$('.modal').html(<%= escape_javascript(render(@event)) %>); 
$('.modal').dialog();
```

In here modal is my hidden div. But it could not pop up any modal dialog. I cannot understand what is the error and why is it not working. Plz can anybody help me to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`$('.modal').html(<%= escape_javascript(render(@event)) %>);`

to

`$('.modal').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@event)) %>");`

From a JS point of view, your code will be invalid because you're not wrapping your render in quotes and it will try to evaluate your HTML.

**EDIT**

If you're trying to link to this on a `show` click, you'll need to use `show.js.erb` to show your modal dialog rather than `create.js.erb`.  `create` will only be called if you `POST` a form to `/events` whereas here it looks like you're trying to show just the details of the event.

Put the code above (with quotes) in the `show.js.erb`, make sure you have a `respond.js` response in your `show` method on the controller, and try it again.

Comment: thanks... but still it didn't work. there is no errors. but it didn't pop-up modal dialog box.

Comment: I've edited my response above, your problem may be due to using wrong action.

Comment: when I did this I got following output..                                    $('.modal').html("<p>\n  <b>Name:<\/b>\n  Ruby\n<\/p>\n\n<p>\n  <b>Start at:<\/b>\n  2011-08-30 00:00:00 UTC\n<\/p>\n\n<p>\n  <b>End at:<\/b>\n  2011-09-01 00:00:00 UTC\n<\/p>\n<p>\n  <b>Trainer:<\/b>\n  Aaaa\n<\/p>\n\n<p>\n  <b>Venue:<\/b>\n  Abc company\n<\/p>\n\n\n\n\n"); 
$('.modal').dialog();                                                  there is no modal dialog loaded.it render partial's details.but it dispaly in show.js.erb

Comment: OK. It sounds like it's evaluating your response as HTML or plain text rather than JS.  What version of Rails are you using? Are you using `rails_ujs` by chance? Can you show me your controller action for `show`; specifically the `respond_to` block?  Can you also double check your console/log file, you should have something similar to this: `Processing by EventsController#show as JS` right when the call comes in; tell me what the `as XX` is.

Comment: Iam using rails 2.3.8 version.                                                                                                                                    respond_to do |format|     
    format.js      
    end                                                                                                                                   there are nothing in log file as Processing by EventsController#show

Answer (score 0):

Could be possible that you didnt install Jquery since the rails default is Prototype library.  I would upgrade to Rails 3.1 which makes it easy to use jquery:

`rails new example -j jquery`

or install jquery:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery